# Correct National Board Certificate for Software Engineering Instructor?

Tags: computer-science, engineering, certification

I am a public high school teacher in Washington State, USA. I have a CTE Teaching Certificate, and teach Software Engineering, Office Applications such as MS Excel, and occasionally IT Fundamentals. Specifically, I don't teach Business concepts, nor communication except at a technical level where business or communication concepts may be integral to learning one of my subjects.

Like most US states, Washington offers significant advantages and bonus pay for teachers who gain National Board (NB) certification. To achieve NB certification, one must select a subject area to certify in. Here is a link to the NB guide for how to select this.
https://www.nbpts.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Choosing_the_Right_Certificate.pdf

Notice that the only top level category that is directly related to my subjects is Career and Technical Education (CTE). On examining this though, one must choose a pathway (middle of p. 6 in above PDF). There are only two plausibly close to what I teach:

- "Engineering, Design, and Fabrication": Sounds good, but the description talks about "repairing roadways, constructing buildings and maintaining power plants". Clearly not aligned to my classes.
- "Information Systems and Technology, Communications, and the Arts": The closest yet because of a brief connection to IT Fundamentals. But it is still described as " communications and
  journalism, fine and performing arts, information systems and technology, and media
  arts—*but the purpose of their activities centers on communication*".

Is that last one really the best / only option for a computer science teacher? If so, is there anything about the National Board Certification process that mitigates the extreme misalignment and omission of consideration for Computer Science as a field?

Thanks in advance for any info or help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is out-of-scope for us; we are mostly "academics" (professors, researchers, lecturers, PhD students) and so we don't know much about certifications for high school teachers. That said: I reviewed the PDF out of interest, and I agree with your analysis; there is a huge gap both for basic computer technology classes and advanced computer science classes (which is strange; both are not so rare). I suspect that you'll have to choose the last one you listed and get a little creative about how your work relates to communication.

Comment: Se also: [this report](https://www.csteachers.org/documents/en-us/3b4a70cd-2a9b-478b-95cd-376530c3e976/1), which describes similar problems across-the-board for teachers in your field.